# python dictionaries and django

Tags: python

hi I have a python dictionary. How do I output the list of keys in django?

If I do something like

> {% for key in dict.keys() %}
>
> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>
>     key
>   </td>
>
> </tr>
> ```
>
> {% endfor %}

I get

> TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '()' from
>   'dict.keys()'

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use {{ key }} inside the loop for this to work. Also:

{% for key in dict.keys %}

Answer (score 1):

You just need `dict.keys`, not `dict.keys()` -- the Django template system will automatically try to call any part of the variable that's callable.

```
{% for key in list.keys %}
<tr><td>{{ key }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the `dict.keys` method in the for loop, and you'll need to actually print out the key var by doing `{{ key }}` in the forloop.   Like this:

```
{% for key in dict.keys %}

<tr>
  <td>
    {{ key }}
  </td>

</tr>   
{% endfor %}
```

See [Accessing Method Calls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#accessing-method-calls) in the django documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `{{ key }}` instead of just `key` and `dict.keys` instead of `dict.keys()`